# Installing Ubuntu 17 but it goes to live session all time

Tags: live-usb

Installing Ubuntu 17.04 on Lenovo Y520. From bootable USB. It gives me 4 option. I'm selecting 2nd option to install ubuntu. (I have already partitioned the HDD)

It prompts to select language. But continue button is not highlighted. Then within 4-5 seconds it change the screen and take me to the live session user.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try booting into a Live USB first. Ubuntu distros should have an installer icon on the desktop.

Comment: When I try this, it says System problem detected. Crash. I think it may be because i'm installing on intel machine while ubuntu 17.04 is only for amd64 available. However live cd is working fine

Comment: As per other posts it seems that amd64 can be installed on intel 64. So now I don't know what is the issue

Comment: This is already reported as bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1637899?comments=all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally installed it. First I have changed the BIOS to ACPI mode. Then installed 16.04.2 which failed due to i/o error. But it had done the partition and all initial work. Then I tried the same steps with 17.04 and it got installed.

Comment: I guess the reason I was getting I/O error because I was using memory card instead of USB.